# How to exit Command Prompt after launching VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here are the steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Open Command Prompt. ( `cmd` )
2. Run `code .` to launching VSCode.
3. Type `exit` and hit **Enter** in the **Command Prompt**.
4. Then the **Command Prompt** is just paused.  I have to wait VSCode exit to let Command Prompt window closed.

[image]

Does anyone know why?  How can I close **Command Prompt** window without exiting VSCode?

Answer (score 10):

I found a solution here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6608. It involves changing the code.cmd file (usually found under "C:\Users\yourUsername\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin").

Changing the fifth line in that file  from

```
call "%~dp0..\Code.exe" "%~dp0..\resources\app\out\cli.js" %*
```

to

```
start "" "%~dp0..\Code.exe" "%~dp0..\resources\app\out\cli.js" %*
```

will make the cmd window close right away. But that change will apparently break some other things (specifically the --wait flag), so I figure it's wiser to leave the code.cmd file alone.

Instead I made a copy ("codeNoCommandPrompt.cmd") right beside it and changed the line in there. That works fine for my usecase, namely having VS Code start on a specific folder alongside a bunch of other programms via a script.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested it (using the latest VSCode 1.24.1), and it does work: the CMD shell session closes immediately when typing "`exit`".

Try calling the code.cmd script with its full path to see if the issue persists:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd" .
```

Try also the same command after having simplified the PATH (for testing)

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
code .
```

Comment: My Command Prompt still not closing again when `exit` after launching VSCode.  I'm using `VSCode 1.24.1` for sure.  I don't know why is that happen.  Can you help?

Comment: @WillHuang Did it work before? (when you accepted the answer). Can you try (with the simplified PATH in place): `start "code" code.cmd .`, or `start /B cmd /C code.cmd .`

Comment: Yes, it works before.  It didn't work now.  I don't know why.  I also tried your `start "code" code.cmd .`, it doesn't works.

Comment: @WillHuang And `start /B cmd /C code.cmd .`? Do you have an error message?

Comment: calling `start` will launch a new window for VSCode.  This is not what I asked.  Also, the new windows doesn't have any error message, it just can't exit and close window before VSCode closed.

Comment: The confusion arises because if a VSCode window is already open, it will be reused and the new "session" of VSCode will immediately exit. On the other hand, if this is the first time VSCode is launched, the code.cmd will stay around until it closes.

Comment: @O'Rooney Does [Nicky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52276897/6309) avoid this confusion?

Comment: I don’t see how it would. The code.cmd explicitly waits for the VSCode exe to Exit before it finishes itself. There’s no way around that without changing the cmd file.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this

**`code . && exit`**

Comment: Please turn this into a more assertive answer, by adding an explanation to the code-only answer.

Comment: Sorry, I can't really explain but I use it and it works fine

Comment: @UtsavBarnwal What OS version do you use?

Comment: I have used it on Windows 10

Comment: Didn't work for me in Windows 10

Answer (score -1):

Check your PATH variable, maybe you have duplicate entries for VS Code
Go System Properties -> Envieronment variables -> select PATH variable then click Edit.
Remove "C:**\Microsoft VS Code".
Leave intact "C:**\Microsoft VS Code\bin"

This happens when you reinstall vscode with "add to PATH" checked