# Hide CMD After opening VScode from Run window in Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmd

I am trying to hide `CMD` After opening VSCode from Run window in Windows and  don't work, I test those solutions

[How to exit Command Prompt after launching VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50881784)

But it didn't work.
[image]

Comment: why do you start VSC from the CMD prompt, just add an icon to your task bar or use to the menu

Comment: The fast way to work with GUI it's using Run window, terminal or make shortcuts  and that question is curious question to learn more.

Comment: `code` is an incomplete file name. Use `code.exe` if that is the filename you want. Additionally do not rely on a system having been configured with the location somewhere within `%PATH%`. Example: ```"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft VS Code\code.exe"```

Comment: @Compo Write `code` in Run window work but this command open VSCode and CMD together.

Comment: It's probably because `code` without an extension is opening `code.cmd`, not `code.exe`. Like I said, use the full path and extension, Example: ```"%LocalAppData%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.exe"```. You should be able to find the actual path of the exe file by typing ```%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe "code.exe"``` in a Command Prompt window, and pressing the `[ENTER]` key.